# Android Studio Project Corrupted

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio couldn't load project settings from project.iml and app.iml

I deleted those files and restarted Android Studio

Now I can't open any file inside the project.

in every file i see this:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="com.google.firebase:firebase-crash-license-12.0.0">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-crash-license-12.0.0.aar/4af1d2fd848fb29a90a1c9eb639021c5/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/firebase-crash-license-12.0.0.aar/4af1d2fd848fb29a90a1c9eb639021c5/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Create new project (with same package and project name) and copy-paste old project's files into newly created project. Don't copy-paste all the folders at a time, start copy-pasting one by one.

Comment: I will try to do that but for as a last option :/

Comment: @Shashanth At the end that did helped , thanks!

Comment: Glad to here that! Happy coding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried "Invalidate Caches", delete folders ".gradle", ".iml" and ".idea" and it didn't help. Finally I installed android preview and it works.

And 5 minutes ago I found another solution. I have fixed this problem by deleting the folder `AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches`.

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem, here's a solution worked for me.

1. Copy the corrupted project directory.
2. Paste it at somewhere else.
3. Import it in Android Studio. (File-> New-> Import project)
4. And uncorrupted project get restored.

PS: You must have original corrupted project. (Means, copy it without tampering project structure)

Answer (score 0):

I think for two possible solutions for this issue:

1. `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`.
2. Delete the folder `caches` inside `.gradle` and reopen the project. This way the Gradle will start downloading the dependencies and will cache them again.

Comment: I cant find caches directory inside .gradle